# Alternative to making a dictionary from text document

Tags: dictionary, python-3.6, txt

I took word pairs from a text file and made a dictionary:

```
x = open('sustantivos.txt', 'r') ## opens file and assigns it to a variable
y = x.read() ## reads open file object and assigns it to variable y
y = str(y).lower().replace(":", "") ## turns open file object into a string, then makes it lower case and replaces ":" with whitespace
z = y.splitlines() # make a list with each element being a word pair string, then assign to variable z

bank = {}

for pair in z: #go through every word pair string
    (key, value) = pair.split() #split the word pair string making a list with two elements, assign these to variable key and value
    bank[key] = value #add key value pair

x.close()
```

For reference this is an excerpt from the text file:

Amour: amor

Anglais: inglés

Argent: dinero

Bateau: barco

My question is: Is there are more efficient or different approach that you would do differently? Also I was curious if my understanding that I include in the comments is correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inline notes are accurate except that line number 2 is where the opened file is read and its contents are turned into a string.  Your use of `str(y)` in the third line is unnecessary and could simply be written as `y.lower()...`

Your parsing strategy is sound as long as you know that the file will always contain lines of key:value pairs on each and every line. However, There are a couple of recommendation I would make.

1. Use a `with` statement when opening files. this avoids errors that can occur if the file isn't closed properly
2. Don't read the whole file in at once.
3. `dict.update` will take an iterable of length 2 as an argument

Using those tips your code can be rewritten as:

```
bank = {}
with open('sustantivos.txt', 'r') as x:
    for line in x:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        bank[key] = value
        # bank.update([line.strip().split(':')]) <- or this
```